# Visual Studio 2010 IntelliSense: hints on F# operators

Tags: visual-studio, f#, intellisense

Is it possible to make Visual Studio to display tooltips on operators?

The following image demonstrates a tooltip hint for a function, but it does not work for operators.

[image: a tooltip hint for a function]

Operators usually have simple type specs like `'T -> 'T -> 'T`, but such hints can be useful for custom ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following Daniel's suggestion, I'm posting a **workaround** that I've been using for myself.
The workaround is only partially helpful, and I'm still looking for any better ideas.

```
let (!><) a = ()
let z1 = op_BangGreaterLess 5
```

This code is fully valid, since an operator expression generates a function with a compiler-generated name. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204.aspx), section "Overloaded Operator Names" for complete list of operator names.

Good news is that `op_BangGreaterLess` supports IntelliSense hints and it also supports "Go to Definition" (<kbd>F12</kbd>) command of IDE, pointing to an original operator declaration.
Bad news is that IntelliSense does not allow rapid entry of the full operator name (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>), so you have to type the entire name manually.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid this is not possible (and even in Visual Studio 2012, I don't get tooltips for operators).

I suppose this could be implemented, but as you say, operators usually have simple types. When using custom operators, these should be probably simple enough so that people can use them without looking at their type (or the associated XML documentation). Otherwise, it might be better to use a named function.

That said, if you're using F# Interactive, then you can easily use that to explore the operator type:

```
> (!><);;
val it : ('a -> unit) = <fun:clo@2>
```

If I cannot use F# Interactive, I usually define a simple dummy symbol to get the IntelliSense:

```
let dummy () = (!><)
```

Note that I added `unit` argument to define a function and avoid value restriction error.

Comment: There's another workaround: `op_BangGreaterLess` is a full-featured synonym that can be used for IntelliSense hints. And it supports `Go to Definition` as well. Unfortunately, rapid typing does not support `op_*`; you have to type them by hand.

Comment: @bytebuster That's a cool workaround, I did not know about that one. I'm wondering if the F# team knew :-)

Comment: @bytebuster: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Note that you will often want your `dummy` function to be `inline`, since otherwise you may see a specialized version of the fully general type.  E.g. contrast `let dummy() = (+)` with `let inline dummy = (+)`.