# How to declare global level overload-able operators?

Tags: syntax, f#, operators

based on: [Is possible to define same-named operator for different argument count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929470/is-possible-to-define-same-named-operator-for-different-argument-count)

I want to define some operator like `+`  but let call `-|-` for example to have

```
let a = -|- 1
let b = 1 -|- 1
let c = 1 -|- 1 1 1 1
```

At least 2 first lines will work for `+` but how can I declare own operator like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a straightforward way to do this in general. You could probably use an `inline` operator with a mix of static member constraints to cover *some* of the cases that you want, but I don't think it will be very elegant.

For some operator names, you can however define a separate *prefix* and  *infix* version, which covers the first two cases:

```
// Prefix version of the operator (when you write e.g. '+. 10')
let (~+.) a = a * 10
// Infix version of the operator (when you write e.g. '1 +. 10')
let (+.) a b = a + b

// Sample use
+. 10
10 +. 20
```

You still won't be able to write `10 +. 20 30 40`, because then you'd need an overloaded infix operator.

It is worth noting that you cannot do this for all operator names. Here is a syntax definition from the [F# specification](http://fsharp.org/about/files/spec.pdf) of the allowed operator names for infix operators:

> infix-or-prefix-op :=
>         +, -, +., -., %, &, &&
>
> prefix-op :=
>         infix-or-prefix-op
>         ~ ~~ ~~~ (and any repetitions of ~)
>         !OP (except !=)

PS: I'm not generally a big fan of custom operators - in some cases, they are nice, but they are difficult to discover (you do not see them in the IntelliSense) and unless you're using standard ones for numerical computing, it is often difficult to understand what they mean. So I would maybe consider other approaches...

Comment: Wow! To be honest that's generally what I wanted to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: I was just looking at your previous question and I thought so... :-). I added a list of allowed operator names.

Comment: But I can't use some, alike I can't use `let inline (~^)`

Comment: Yeah, the number of operators you can use is quite restricted (and it is not entirely clear to me what will actually work...)

Comment: +1 on what Tomas said about custom operators, they can make a library hard to learn, with the lack of intellisense they rely on internal knowledge or documentation to be used effectively.

Comment: @TomasPetricek: I've never understood the lack of Intellisense tooltips for operators. For those interested, there are [workarounds](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12182640/162396).

Answer (score 1):

So what about a Discriminated Union:

```
type RHS = 
|One of int
|Two of int * int
...
```

then

```
let (-|-) a b =
    match b with
    |One(a) -> ...
    |Two(a,b) -> ...
     ...
```

Call it with:

```
1 -|- One(1)
1 -|- Two(1,1)
....
```

Comment: Thank you for advice but it's not the same level I wan to get. I don't like the look of `let a = 1 -|- Zero()` I want `-|- 1`. So maybe it's not possible, I'm just interested if that could be possible.